# Is "before" a preposition or adverb here?

Tags: grammar

In

> Six questions to ask yourself before making a decision

... is "before" a preposition because it is the beginning of a prepositional phrase? Or is it an adverb since it's followed by a verb? (Or is "making" even a verb, or is it a gerund?!)

Comment: It's a subordinating conjunction introducing the adverbial clause _before you make a decision_, which is transformed into a participial phrase _before making a decision_.

Comment: It's a preposition, interpreted in parallel with such a phrase as "ask ... before noon".  McCawley discusses the traditional characterization as subordinate conjunction versus Jespersen's analysis as preposition, and M endorses Jespersen (in *The Syntactic Phenomena of English*).

Comment: @JohnLawler But only if you believe in subordinating conjunctions. Otherwise it's a preposition!

Comment: Oh, OK. I can live with that, as long as we can have intransitive prepositions along with clausal-object transitive prepositions.